# Sort Products by Image Available on Folder in Open Cart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

On Search Page, I want to search a similar product and would like to view all products sorted from Image Available (from my folder) to No image available.

Here's the code:

```
if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
  $order = $this->request->get['order'];
} else {
  $order = 'ASC';
}
```